# How to hide/display specific RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility

I have a contacts list RecyclerView, where the first item (position 0) holds the user's details. When the search icon in the toolbar is pressed, I want that entry to be hidden from the user.

I've tried using `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on it, and, although the entry is hidden, the space it occupied was still there, much like setting `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. How can I toggle the visibility of this specific entry to VISIBLE/GONE in my RecyclerView, or how can I set its height only to 0dp?

EDIT:

My xml is quite simple, it comprises of simply a recyclerView and a FAB. My adapter code is as below.

```
ContactsAdapter(
            Context context,
            List<LinphoneContact> contactsList,
            ContactViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener,
            SelectableHelper helper) {
        super(helper);
        mContext = context;
        updateDataSet(contactsList);
        mClickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        // For the first position only, use the user's own contact card
        // For all the rest, use the contact card
        switch (viewType) {
            case USER_CARD_VIEW:
                View userCard =
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                .inflate(R.layout.contacts_user_card, parent, false);
                return new ContactViewHolder(userCard, mClickListener);
            case CONTACT_CARD_VIEW:
                View contactCard =
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                .inflate(R.layout.contact_cell, parent, false);
                return new ContactViewHolder(contactCard, mClickListener);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Remove the user's card when searching contacts - DOES NOT WORK, MAKES ALL FIRST ITEMS
        // INVISIBLE
        //        if (position == 0) {
        //            if (mIsSearchMode) holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //            else holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //        }

        if (position != 0) {

            LinphoneContact contact = (LinphoneContact) getItem(position - 1);

            holder.name.setText(contact.getFullName());

            if (!mIsSearchMode) {
                String fullName = contact.getFullName();
                if (fullName != null && !fullName.isEmpty()) {
                    holder.separatorText.setText(String.valueOf(fullName.charAt(0)));
                }
            }

            // Separator as in the big capital letter on the left to indicate sections
            holder.separator.setVisibility(
                    mIsSearchMode
                                    || (getPositionForSection(getSectionForPosition(position))
                                            != position)
                            ? View.GONE
                            : View.VISIBLE);

            holder.linphoneFriend.setVisibility(
                    contact.isInFriendList() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

            ContactAvatar.displayAvatar(contact, holder.avatarLayout);

            boolean isOrgVisible = LinphonePreferences.instance().isDisplayContactOrganization();
            String org = contact.getOrganization();
            if (org != null && !org.isEmpty() && isOrgVisible) {
                holder.organization.setText(org);
                holder.organization.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.organization.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            holder.delete.setVisibility(isEditionEnabled() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.delete.setChecked(isSelected(position));
            //        } else {
            //            // TODO - user's card should have whole and voicemail onClick listeners
        }

        //        Log.d("contactsAdapter", "Position: " + position);
        //        Log.d("contactsAdapter", "Section for position: " +
        // getSectionForPosition(position));
        //        Log.d(
        //                "contactsAdapter",
        //                "The other thingy: " +
        // getPositionForSection(getSectionForPosition(position)));
    }

    // +1 item count to account for user's contact card
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContacts.size() + 1;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if (position >= getItemCount()) return null;
        return mContacts.get(position);
    }

    public void setIsSearchMode(boolean set) {
        mIsSearchMode = set;
    }

    [...]

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? USER_CARD_VIEW : CONTACT_CARD_VIEW;
    }
```

Essentially, I don't add the first item to my list of items, but instead I add it to the recyclerView, and shift my list of items by one position up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> although the entry is hidden, the space it occupied was still there

- may be because you are hiding the child but its parent is still there with its `height` or `padding` given

> How can I toggle the visibility of this specific entry to VISIBLE/GONE in my RecyclerView

- Toggle the visibility of parent

In your onBindViewHolder

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    if (isButtonPressed) {
        viewHolder.parentViewId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        viewHolder.parentViewId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Create a `public boolean isButtonPressed;` and when you press the `button` make it `true` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: That makes sense, so I would have to retrieve the view itself and not the item of the view. I have tried setting `mContactsList.getChildViewHolder(mContactsList.getChildAt(0)).itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, but my app crashes saying I'm attempting to retrieve a null object reference?

Comment: Just get the reference in the adapter and toggle the visibility. Simple.

Comment: Apologies, could you try explaining a bit further? I've tried to retrieve the view in my adapter in some method (i.e. outside onBindViewHolder), but can't figure out how to retrieve the view at position 0. Using `holder.item.setVisibility()` affects all adapter items.

Comment: post your xml file so I can be specific what you how you have to change it

Comment: My xml is simple so I updated the question with my adapter code. Let me know if the information is inadequate.

Comment: Last question - itemView does not hide the row itself - instead I'm only hiding the contents of the view and the row retains its height. How can I retrieve the parentViewId so I can hide the whole row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208241/discussion-between-makarand-and-george).